# installing npm module karma fails with build error message

Tags: node.js, npm, karma-runner

I'm getting the following error when trying to install the Karma NPM module.  Not sure what's going on, and I'm having trouble making head or tails of the error.  Google search didn't bring up any help.  Would appreciate any insight.

```
> fsevents@0.3.1 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents
> node-gyp rebuild

SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/.node
SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/.node: Finished
CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
In file included from ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:29:
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/string:46:10: fatal error: 'bits/stringfwd.h' file not found
#include <bits/stringfwd.h>
     ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-              gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:807:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.0.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"     "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.28
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.13.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.3.1

> ws@0.4.32 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bufferutil.node
SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bufferutil.node: Finished
CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/validation.node
SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/validation.node: Finished 
karma@0.12.30 karma
├── di@0.0.1
├── graceful-fs@2.0.3
├── rimraf@2.2.8
├── colors@0.6.2
├── mime@1.2.11
├── q@0.9.7
├── minimatch@0.2.14 (sigmund@1.0.0, lru-cache@2.5.0)
├── optimist@0.6.1 (wordwrap@0.0.2, minimist@0.0.10)
├── glob@3.2.11 (inherits@2.0.1, minimatch@0.3.0)
├── source-map@0.1.42 (amdefine@0.1.0)
├── lodash@2.4.1
├── useragent@2.0.10 (lru-cache@2.2.4)
├── log4js@0.6.21 (semver@1.1.4, async@0.2.10, readable-stream@1.0.33)
├── http-proxy@0.10.4 (pkginfo@0.3.0, utile@0.2.1)
├── chokidar@0.12.5 (async-each@0.1.6, readdirp@1.3.0)
├── connect@2.26.6 (fresh@0.2.4, cookie@0.1.2, pause@0.0.1, cookie-signature@1.0.5, response-time@2.0.1, vhost@3.0.0, basic-auth-connect@1.0.0, on-headers@1.0.0, bytes@1.0.0, media-typer@0.3.0, parseurl@1.3.0, cookie-parser@1.3.3, depd@0.4.5, qs@2.2.4, connect-timeout@1.3.0, debug@2.0.0, method-override@2.2.0, finalhandler@0.2.0, serve-favicon@2.1.7, type-is@1.5.5, multiparty@3.3.2, express-session@1.8.2, compression@1.1.2, csurf@1.6.4, errorhandler@1.2.3, morgan@1.3.2, serve-index@1.2.1, serve-static@1.6.4, body-parser@1.8.4)
└── socket.io@0.9.16 (base64id@0.1.0, policyfile@0.0.4, redis@0.7.3, socket.io-client@0.9.16)
```

Comment: It looks like it is not finding a String library when compiling with `node-gyp`: `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/string:46:10: fatal error: 'bits/stringfwd.h' file not found`. Is it your environment setup correctly?

Comment: @MarcoCI not sure, what constitutes a correctly setup environment?

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of tedious testing, I found that the issue was that I was not running the latest version of the command line tools for XCode.  OOf... make sure to check for updates kids!